cron job is not executing a python script
i have a cron job that i expect it to execute a python script. Here is the cron job :
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3.8 /config/workspace/test/twg_api.py >> config/workspace/logfile.log 2>&1

problem is i cannot find log file and python script is not executed (or at least i don't have the final result that the script should do). For the context, the script should perform get requsest to an api endpoint and process data then store it in an influxDB bucket.. the goal of cron job is to automate the whole process..
So i added explicitly the path in crontab , PATH=/path/to/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin
then set up a bash script "cron.sh" to recall the command that i would normally give in the terminal;
#!/bin/sh
python3 /absolute/path/to/my_script.py

and added log to crontab. so my crontab looks like:
PATH=/path/to/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin

* * * * * /absolute/path/to/cron.sh >> /absolute/path/to_log_file/clogs.log 2>&1

problem is i have nothing in log file (blank file) and i don't understand where things are messing up.
Any helps on this ?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4
Conda info
conda info 

     active environment : base
    active env location : /config/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /config/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 24.5.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.12.2.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=haswell
                          __conda=24.5.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __linux=4.18.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /config/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /config/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /config/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /config/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /config/miniconda3/envs
                          /config/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/24.5.0 requests/2.32.2 CPython/3.12.2 Linux/4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64 ubuntu/20.04.4 glibc/2.31 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/24.1.0 libmambapy/1.5.8 aau/0.4.4 c/. s/. e/.
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


nothing to go on and it looks like a coding question. add a log file to the scriot and write something to it so you know where the script stops. "cron job is not executing a python script"  Look at /var/log/ and there should be a log file that tells you it does get executed.

and "config/workspace/logfile.log" is missing a /

Needs details. Please edit the question and add what version of Ubuntu you are using. How the cron job was configured, exact info.

Note that 1 * * * * runs at 1 minute past every hour; have you waited at least 1 hour for the result?

@steeldriver yes, it has been 1 day now

You should replace twg_api.py with code that just prints "Hello world" (or something similar).  At least you can find out whether it is a problem with the Python script or how cron is running.

@Rinzwind under /var/log there is no log file

Yes there is a log. specifically syslog. That one explains cron is running and what line it executed,

... or (on a modern systemd system, and assuming an ordinary user-crontab) something like journalctl -xeu cron _AUDIT_LOGINUID="$(id -u)"

I figured it out. I'm sharing what i did in case anyone faces same issue.
So i removed the shell script as basically it complicates debugging and used directly cron as follows:









(date && /config/miniconda3/envs/api_env/bin/python3 /config/workspace/test/twg_api.py) >> /config/workspace/logapi.txt 2>&1
this solved my problem and does what i expect.









